# UIPickerView for available countries

Tags: iphone, ios4

I need help regarding UIPickerView, in my  application i have to display UIPickerView with available countries . If any body has already implemented  country picker please share the code.

Thanks

Comment: please share the code???

Answer (score 20):

Here's a countries plist that I created for this purpose:

https://gist.github.com/vilcsak/c205dfd153a3e465f47e

Implementation should be pretty straightforward, but here's a bit of our code:

```
- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        self.countries = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Countries" ofType:@"plist"]];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    self.currentCountry = [[self.countries objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"code"];
    self.countryLabel.text = [[self.countries objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"name"];
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return self.countries.count;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [[self.countries objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"name"];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for providing the plist with your code Andrew!

Answer (score 3):

You can get a list of available country names like this:

```
self.countryArray = [NSMutableArray new];
for (NSString *countryCode in [NSLocale ISOCountryCodes]) {
    NSString *country = [[NSLocale systemLocale] displayNameForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode value:countryCode];
    [self.countryArray addObject: country];
}
```

and here are some UIPicker delegate methods:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    self.countryLabel.text = [self.countryArray objectAtIndex:row];
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return self.countryArray.count;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [self.countryArray objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make an array of available country and use this array in these delgate methods and data source methods

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

--> return value at index of array

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

number of elements in array

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView

return 1;
```

Comment: thanks isha for reply .. actually i need to find out how to get available countries using by  API .

Comment: 0 down vote accept
 

Is there is any way to invoke native address country selection controller ??

Comment: [NSLocale ISOCountryCodes] gets you an NSArray of country codes as NSStrings. You can get the display names for each using [[NSLocale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode value:countryCode];

Answer (score 1):

You can take the countries.plist from the following like and use that for ur picker input

http://code.google.com/p/reviewscraper/source/browse/trunk/Countries.plist?spec=svn22&r=22

Answer (score 0):

here is the link to the blog post regarding country list data picker in a popover.
http://iosblogl.blogspot.in/2015/11/pickerview-popover-with-country-list.html

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.